# default sound and vibration when getting a notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, vibration

I am trying to send push notifications to my ios app. The device can successfully receive the push notifications and I am trying also receive sounds and vibrations. When the notification is recieved it is just silent.

in my app delegate i tried to add

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("serInfo=", userInfo)
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
      AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
        
    }
    else if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .background {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
    }
}
```

but the notification still comes through silent. Is there a way to implement the default sounds and vibrations?

I also already have

```
   func attemptToRegisterForNotifications(application: UIApplication) {

  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
      UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

   // application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

set so the user already agreed to receive the vibrations and sounds.

```
var payload = {
  notification: {
    title: userThatSent.name + ' sent you a message',
    body: message.text
    "sound" : "default"

     }
   };
```

when I add the above I am receiving the below issue in the terminal.

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

/Users/wilcox.323/Downloads/OddJobs-master/functions/index.js:220
        "sound": "default"
        ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1116:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:15:15
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:53:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1200:30)
```

Comment: You have to set it from your server in sound key of payload.

Comment: I edited my question to show my payload. Would I be setting vibrations and sounds here??

Comment: @shraddha11 would this also play a vibration as well as a sound?

Comment: @shraddha11 could you help me understand where this goes?

Comment: yes. Please refer this for more clarity. https://medium.com/@dmennis/the-3-ps-to-custom-alert-sounds-in-ios-push-notifications-9ea2a2956c11